# Django- Query filter, with a foreign relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, django, django-models, django-views

I've got a querying problem in Django, using a MySQL Database, that I'm having trouble solving, due to being new to this.

I have 2 models, Area and Form.
An Area might have 1 or more Forms associated with it, so it has a foreign relationship with Forms:

```
form = models.ManyToManyField(Form)
```

In one of my Django Views, I want to get all the Forms that are "area-less", i.e. not associated with any Areas, from the Database, and use them in a template.

For example, if I query the DB like this (polls being the app name):

```
SELECT `polls_area_form`.`id`,
    `polls_area_form`.`area_id`,
    `polls_area_form`.`form_id`
FROM `myproject`.`polls_area_form`;
```

I get:

> id area_id    form_id
>
> 1  1  1
>
> 2 1   3
>
> 3 2   3

Showing that in this example scenario, Area 1 is associated with Forms 1 and 3. Area 2 is associated with Form 3. So, here I'd want to retrieve Form 2 due to not being associated with any Areas.

In my Views, in a simple situation where someone wanted to retrieve all Forms no matter what, I'd simply use `all_forms = Form.objects.filter()` (Python) and then use that to render my response to the request.

I'm having trouble figuring out what the filter should be in this situation, or if actual SQL statements are necessary here.

From reading the Django documentation, I feel maybe I need to use an `.exclude(some rule)` after the filter, but I don't know what the rule for it would look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to just do

```
Form.objects.filter(area=None)
```

assuming that your area class is called `Area` and have not added a custom `related_name`

[Read more here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

Comment: It works! It was actually pretty simple. I thought I might have to do some weird querying. thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can try this.

```
Form.objects.filter(area__isnull=True)
```

Comment: since @user6731765 answered first I gave them the checkmark, but this works too